# Calling a function within a function within a class

Tags: python, class, beautifulsoup

So there's this website that posts something I want to buy at a random time of day for a limited amount of time and I want to write something to send a message to my phone when a new url is posted to that webpage.

I planned on doing this by counting the number of links on the page (since it's rarely updated) and checking it every 5 minutes against what it was 5 minutes before that, then 5 minutes later check it against what it was 10 minutes before that, 5 minutes later check what it was 15 minutes before that... and if it's greater than what it originally was, send a message to my phone.  Here's what I have so far:

```
class url_alert:
    url = '' 

    def link_count(self):
        notifyy=True
        while notifyy:
            try:
                page = urllib.request.urlopen(self.url)
                soup = bs(page, "lxml") 
                links=[]
                for link in soup.findAll('a'):
                    links.append(link.get('href'))
                    notifyy=False
                print('found', int(len(links)), 'links')
            except:
                print('Stop making so many requests')
                time.sleep(60*5)
        return len(links)


    def phone(self):
        self= phone
    phone.message = client.messages.create(to="", from_="",body="") 
        print('notified')


    def looper(self):
        first_count = self.link_count()
        print('outside while')

        noty = True
        while noty:
            try:
                second_count = self.link_count()
                print('before compare')

                if second_count == first_count:
                    self.phone()
                    noty = False
            except:
                print('not quite...')
                time.sleep(60)


alert = url_alert()
alert.looper()
```

As a test, I decided to set the if statement that determines whether or not to send a message as equal but the loop kept on running.  Am I calling the functions within the looper function the right way?

Comment: Where is self.phone defined? I'm only seeing the definition of self.__phone.

Comment: Also, what's the first line of __phone, `self= phone`, supposed to do?

Comment: this is my first attempt at writing my own class for a project I created for myself.  I thought self=phone was like a 'link' between the message variable  and the phone function.

Comment: You can just use `while True:` and then use `break` to stop the loop instead of the `noty` variable.

Comment: If you want to add another property to the object, you use `self.message =`. There's no "link between the message variable and the phone function".

Comment: i think i need to read up on self in the context of classes.  i've only been python-ing a couple of months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to eliminate the try block, as it is now, if self.phone() takes an exception you will never leave the loop

```
def looper(self):
    first_count = self.link_count()
    while True:
        if first_count != self.link_count():
            self.phone()
            break
        time.sleep(60)
```